# Is there any way to cultivate viruses without cells?

Tags: virology

I know what viruses are. They replicate only inside the living cells, and so on, and so on.

I just interesting maybe there is some progress in this field. I don't know exactly, but I suppose before invention of the nutrient agar microorganisms were cultivated on substrates like eggs, potatoes, meat etc. Perhaps there is the same story for viruses.

Comment: No. `A virus is a small infectious agent that replicates only inside the living cells of other organisms.` -[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virus#Effects_on_the_host_cell)

Comment: +1'd and it doesn't seem like a homework question. It seems the OP want to tell they knows virus doesn't grow if not in living cell- but if there is any latter-discovery of any virus-like particle growing outside living cell.

Comment: I agree with @AlwaysConfused - I see no reason to close or put this question on hold, it does not seem like a homework question, especially after the OP's recent edits I would suggest the hold be removed.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience in this field to give a full answer, but just for the OP's information, a couple things. First, viruses depend on many key proteins from their hosts. To have any possibility of growing a virus outside a cell, you would have to provide all these proteins, plus the proteins that support/regulate those proteins, a source of ATP, etc. Soon the list of ingredients is essentially just a cell, and (many) cells are fairly easy to grow, so I don't think there is a lot of motivation to finding a way to cultivate a virus outside of a cell, and it would take a lot of work.

Comment: Voted to reopen. I was reading a paper from the 30's which claimed to cultivate Vaccinia in the absence of living cells. However a later paper admitted that they couldn't be sure there were no living cells in the media. Of course, given what we now know, contamination with life cells seems most likely.

Comment: It depends. Some viruses (like Vaccinia used above) are highly complex and would need a cell to be synthesized (with today's tech). If you take simple viruses, say [Poliovirus](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1490301/), you could make the RNA and that alone could be infectious if placed in a cell. This isn't a true virus though, more of a viroid. That being said, take [PCV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porcine_circovirus), the single protein will self-assemble and incorporate vDNA, while it might not have been done, this could be theoretically be made in vitro.

Comment: [PCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymerase_chain_reaction) may be called as a quite similar situation where outside the cell a piece of nucleic acid replicated.

Comment: @Artem Very helpful information.